# How to show the total amount of gender specific registered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a admin control panel, and I am on the last step which is the statistics.

How can I create stats for registered Users who selected `Male` as their `gender`?

example:

545 Male registered users

323 Female registered users

So I would like to output the above example in my views. I am not sure how to count the rows for the `gender` column.

Comment: In terms of what you're actually looking for, I'm not sure what you're asking. I assume a user will have some kind of gender field, or gender_id. Count those rows.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking. How to count the rows and output in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a model `User` with a field `gender` Then you could add class methods to your user class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.total_males
    where(gender: 'male').count
  end
  def self.total_females
    where(gender: 'female').count
  end
end
```

Then in your view

```
<%= User.total_males %> Male registered users
<%= User.total_females %> Female registered users
```

You will also want an index you your gender field to make the queries fast. You can add the index in a migration.

Comment: A slight nitpick, the expectation with `scope` is that it returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object. Its bad practice to return anything else (despite being technically possible). These would be better as class methods instead. Or, remove the `.count` from the scope and invoke it inline (`.total_males.count`).

Answer (score 4):

There is no enough info you provided, so here is a little telepathy :)
I suppose you have a model `User` with a `:gender` attribute (string 'male' or 'female') in it.
So getting needed counts will look like this:

```
User.group(:gender).count
```

This will provide SQL query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, gender AS gender FROM `users` GROUP BY `users`.`gender`
```

And you will get a hash like this:

```
{ 'male' => 545, 'female' => 323 }
```

Use this as you want ;)

UPD: If you need extra filtering (such as registered or something), just add extra where clauses.

UPD2: This solution is for fetching all statistics at the time. If you want statistics for only one specific gender, you should use an approach in  **JosephL**'s answer below.